# Meaning of "house" regading Parliament

Tags: meaning

> Mr. President, the house we sit in today has witnessed many extraordinary moments in history.  It’s where governments made the difficult decision to send young men and women to war.  Decisions that forever changed our country and the world.  [Prime Minister Trudeau and President Obama deliver addresses to Parliament](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5HWUx9OYVs)

This is a speech by Prime Minister Trudeau in the Parliament, and I would like to know what "the house" means here.

Does it mean the Parliament building? or the members of Parliament?

the Oxford says:

> the House)  (in the UK) the House of Commons or Lords; (in the US) the House of Representatives.

and

> A building in which people meet for a particular activity. [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/house)

So which is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very common for a word to mean both the building, and the users of that building.

> Church can mean a building for Christian worship, or a community of Christians.
>
> Circus can be a large tent, or a style of performance, or the community of people who perform that way.

Buildings that host parliaments are often called "houses", as are the community of politicians that use them. Note that in this latter sense, the word is often capitalised as "House".

In this particular example, "house" means the building. But the house has been personified. This is figurative language in which a thing is given human characteristics: "This house has witnessed...."

Comment: Technically, this figurative use of "house" for "the members of parliament" is called [metonymy](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/metonymy).